# Why I don't see companion object component of extended class?

Tags: kotlin, companion-object

I have an abstract class:

[`abstract class Vec2t`](https://github.com/elect86/glm/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/vec/Vec2t.kt#L15)

and an extending class:

[`class Vec2 : Vec2t`](https://github.com/elect86/glm/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/vec/_2/Vec2.kt#L20)

`Vec2t` has the following [companion object](https://github.com/elect86/glm/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/vec/Vec2t.kt#L120-L125):

```
companion object {

    @JvmField val length = 2
}
```

But when I type `Vec2.length`, then it's marked as unresolved reference...

Why? What am I missing?

Comment: What are you talking about? There is no companion object in `Vec2t` and the compaion object of `Vec2` doesn't look like what you have given above.

Comment: I checked again and I saw your `length` is probably actually named `SIZE`.

Comment: sorry, old code, I just pushed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Kotlin, a `companion object` is just a specially marked `object` inside your class. You can omit its name, and it will get the default name of `Companion`, and you also get the convenience of being able to use the `MyClass.myProperty` syntax instead of `MyClass.Companion.myProperty` to access its members. It is, however, still just a nested `object`.

Imagine how things would work if it was a regular nested object instead of a companion:

```
abstract class Vec2t {

    object LengthKeeper {
        val length = 2
    }

}

class Vec2 : Vec2t()
```

You could access the `length` via `Vec2t.LengthKeeper.length`, but of course you couldn't access it as `Vec2.LengthKeeper.length`, because the `Vec2` class does not have a nested object called `LengthKeeper`.

Marking a variable inside the companion object `@JvmStatic` does generate a static variable for `length` inside `Vec2t` in the bytecode, but you can only access that from Java, where writing the following does in fact work with your code:

```
Vec2 v = new Vec2();
int length = Vec2.getLength();
```

As for solving this in Kotlin, if you really have to access the property of the base class through `Vec2` with that syntax, you'll probably have to do something like this:

```
class Vec2 : Vec2t() {

    companion object {
        val length get() = Vec2t.length
    }

}
```